# How to update the language in a existing node entity?

Tags: 8, nodes, i18n-l10n

Using `kint($node)` gives me some available methods to use but none seems to be able to set the language of the node.

By guessing, I found `$node->langcode`, which gives me a method `setLangcode($langcode)`, but it does not work.

After loading the `$node->langcode->setLangcode('cat');` and `$node->save();`, the node in the interface does not have the updated language.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Did you get a chance to try my suggestion?

Comment: Hello, super late response, sorry. But i could not try your solution, but it looks good, gave it a +1

Answer (score 5):

You should be using the `get()`/`set()` methods (of the FieldableEntityInterface), sth like this:

```
// Get the current node's language.
$node->get('langcode')->value;
// Set the current node's language.
$node->set('langcode', 'de');
// Save the node to persist the change.
$node->save();
```

Hope this answers the question for you.

Comment: This will not update the langcode column in the node_field_data table.

Comment: Probably related issue on drupal.org: [Allow default_langcode field value to be changed](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2443991)

Comment: Testing with Drupal 8.9.13, using the above code to change a node's language from 'und' to 'en', seems to work as a charm. It also updates node_field_data table and all field tables.

Comment: Following up above comment, you have to ensure that there is a pathauto pattern specified for the CTs of the nodes to get updated, else their path aliases will get lost.